# Search by category Exchange Server EWS

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I need to get all the emails that have a specific category name, how would I do this?

Right now I have this:

```
var col = new List<SearchFilter>();
col.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Categories, "Processed"));
var filter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or, col.ToArray());

FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(
    WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,
    filter,
    new ItemView(10)
);
```

But that gives me a `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException` that says `{"The Contains filter can only be used for string properties."}`

How would I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK as of Exchange 2010, category is a multi value field so it does not work with search filters.  However, you can search categories using [AQS](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchangesearch/archive/2012/03/10/how-to-use-aqs-to-construct-complex-discovery-queries.aspx).  The following code should do the trick.

```
ExchangeService service = GetService(); 

var iv = new ItemView(1000);
string aqs = "System.Category:Processed";
FindItemsResults<Item> searchResult = null;
do
{
    searchResult = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, aqs, iv);
    foreach (var item in searchResult.Items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
    }
    iv.Offset += searchResult.Items.Count;
} while (searchResult.MoreAvailable == true);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have any idea how to search for emails that do NOT have category "Processed"?

Comment: @user3182508: All you have to do is use NOT: string aqs = "NOT System.Category:Processed";

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code, to find all messages, which do NOT have set the category "Processed" and which have been received after a given date.

```
                SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And,
                                   new SearchFilter.Not(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.Categories, "Processed")),                                       
                                   new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(EmailMessageSchema.DateTimeReceived, minDate));
```